# SASS: Extending Classess vs Variables

Tags: sass

Lately when using Sass, I have been extending classes as a substitute for variables.

For example:

**-Using a variable**

```
$small-font: 12px

p {
font-size: $small-font
}
```

**-Extending a class**

```
.small-font {
font-size:12px;
}

p {
@extend .small-font;
}
```

The advantage of extending classes is that it makes it easier to make your code responsive. For example, I can wrap  `.small-font` in a media query, which wouldn't be possible with a variable.

My question is: Are there any disadvantages to using extended classes in this way?
I know the output tends to lump all the classes together (which can make debugging more cumbersome), but are there any other potential problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues. One is simply the crazy-slippery-slope nature of it. This will come back to bite you as a maintenance issue. A class-per-property just doesn't make sense as a code organization scheme. That doesn't mean you're far off - @extend is great for something like this, within reason.

Reason is the key: your groupings should make sense as groupings. While html-style content-semantics are not important with @extends, there should still be a sense of semantic organization. I've seen the term "visual-semantics" floating around for this. Your naming should go beyond describing the effect, and describe the visual reason for it instead. not %yellow, but %highlight-text. Not %red, but %warning. Not what, but why.

The other problem is the cascade. The order of your output code is very important, because it affects the cascade (which is an essential part of CSS). With this approach, you will find yourself fighting against the cascade on a regular basis - because you are giving up control of the code order. @extend is great for broad and simple default groupings, but it isn't any good at cascade overrides.

Comment: Thanks! That explained it perfectly.